# view or redirect in laravel not working for another method

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new in Laravel 5 framework. I make a form. In the form, I create one button to search inventory codes and then fill the text input in the form. The Controllers are work well. But, when I try return view('cari'), the browser doesn't show up anything.  These is my codes: 
in Controller:

```
public function search(){
      echo "212";
      return view('cari');
}
```

The index method in my controller works well.

```
public function checkAction()
    {
        if(Input::get('submit')) {
            $this->create(); 
        } else if(Input::get('cari')) {
            $this->search();
        }
    }
```

Then, I try another way use return redirect('cari'); in my controller with no display anything.
If I edit my post in `routes.php` and directly call myController@search it does display the cari.blade.php. But, I want from the search form trigger to browse inventory items. Could you give me some clues?.

This is my permintaan.blade.php which i created a button to checkAction():

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/permintaan') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Inventaris</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kodeInventaris" value="{{ old('kdInventaris') }}">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="cari" value="cari">
                                Cari
                            </button>
                        </div>
....
</form>
```

These is my create and store functions:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->except('_token');
        $validator = $this->validator($data);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }
        $this->store($data);
        $request->find($request);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permintaan berhasil diinput');
    }

    public function store(array $data){
        Permintaan::create([
            'kdInventaris' => $data['kodeInventaris'],
            'namaInventaris' => $data['namaInventaris'],
            'jenis' => $data['optInventaris'],
            'jumlah' => $data['jumlah'],
            'spesifikasi' => $data['spesifikasi'],
            'keterangan' => $data['keterangan'],
        ]);
    }
```

when redirect. It works, but got a blank page again. and replace with echo.
It works, but has this message and got a successful redirect:
"HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2015 16:04:33 GMT Location: http://localhost:8000/permintaan Redirecting to http://localhost:8000/permintaan."
I wonder with my `return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permintaan berhasil diinput');`

Comment: After `return view('cari');` returning the view you can able to see only the blade.. If you want to proceed it from there , then you should add a form action there and search from there.

Comment: i have created the action in  cari.blade.php. Sorry, if i don't understand what you mean. i debug and the search function work. My problem is i can't see anything when trigger return view('cari');

Comment: Are you calling checkaction() from your blade ??

Comment: No. I'm calling checkAction() when in controller. I defined it in routes.php
`Route::post('permintaan', 'MyController@checkAction');`

Comment: Ah, that's ok.. I am asking that.. Do you have the form action which points to checkaction() i.e., if you search anything in your blade then it moves to the checkaction function ?

Comment: i have edited my post to add new information. That's my blade which refer to checkAction()

Comment: Oh, that's good.. You route `permintaan` refers to `checkAction` ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see. It works well to check which button was clicked. Just the view doesn't show anything when i clicked the 'cari' button

Comment: Your blade seems ok.. Do you have any form before this form ?

Comment: No, The blade above is when i get the Permintaan@index in routes.php returning view permintaan

Comment: Can you try this inside your function https://eval.in/373344 ?

Comment: Yes, the function seems ok.

Comment: You getting form submitted message in  browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the operation and not returning any view in your controller

You can do it by

```
public function checkAction()
    {
        if(Input::get('submit')) {
            $this->create(); 
            return view('cari')->with('message', 'Succesfully created');
        } else if(Input::get('cari')) {
            $this->search();
             return view('cari')->with('message', 'Search Done');
        }
    }
```

Note :

I dont know any of your view name so i am using the same name `cari` you can replace it with any view that you have.

Comment: Thanks so much, i just forgot to paste return view('cari') to the eval.in. But, i have tried on my program. Still blank page. But the echo return the string that the methode work. Updated in the eval.in

Comment: You're welcome.. That eval is just for a test .. Here's the eval i have for you now :) https://eval.in/373350

Comment: If my answer helped you. You can accept it by clicking on the Tick Mark near to my Answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry. My reputations isn't enough. But, i will try to more active in the stack overflow to get more reputations.

Comment: Ah, forgive my stupidity :). I have done accepted your answer

Comment: I replaced the `return view('cari')` to `echo view('cari')`. It did render the cari.blade.php. But, now I got a blank page when call redirect on my create() method. Edited post again. :) Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: That's ok :) Ah, you should not add it to your existing question, you should add it in new question..